# 'System.OutOfMemoryException' when using ReadAllText() method

Tags: c#, replace, out-of-memory, flat-file

I have a tab delimited file with 8,000,000+ rows that have some rogue tabs.

For example:

```
a->b->c->d
a->b->c->-->-->--d
a->b->c->d
a->b->c->d
```

I have a method to rectify the rogue tabs (3 tabs to 1 tab) as follows:

```
string text = File.ReadAllText(filePath);
text = text.Replace("\t\t\t", "\t");
File.WriteAllText(filePath, text);
```

The above code block produces the following error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' occurred
>   in mscorlib.dll

How can I read and and write just one row at a time so that the whole file is not in memory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`File.ReadLines`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503.aspx) gives you a lazy `IEnumerable<string>`. You can iterate over that instead and only load one line at a time.

You'll need to write to a different file than you read from, though. You can delete/rename when you finish.

Here's a one-liner that processes the file:

```
File.WriteAllLines(outputFile, 
    File.ReadLines(inputFile).
    Select(t => t.Replace("\t\t\t", "\t"))
);
```

Comment: Would I instanciate a FileStream object for this method?

Comment: You could, or use any other method for writing a file that doesn't require the entire contents in memory at once. See my edit for a simpler way than FileStream.

Comment: Actually, since you're only ever removing characters, you *could* probably do this without the temporary file, but this way is simpler.

Comment: @Blorgbeard How could you do this without the temporary file? Would it not require an insane amount of copying. Each character you delete would in effect require you to copy the whole of the tail of the file.

Comment: @aron, you wouldn't delete characters, just overwrite. Read a line, remove characters, write it back. You would keep track of the current read position and the current write position. Since you're only ever writing the same or fewer characters than you read, you wouldn't stomp on yourself. When you finish, just truncate the file after the last write.

Comment: @Aron *shrug* it's more space-efficient and no slower. If you're processing 100GB files you would probably prefer it.

Comment: @Blorgbeard while your solution works...How can I find and replace each line without having to write to a new file?

Comment: @JeffOrris I briefly explained it in the comment above. The code would be a lot more complex, you'd have to load the file in chunks (making sure these chunks didn't cross line boundaries), keep track of where you read and write, seek around the file... I suggest you ask a new question if you're interested in more details.